# How do I display an unknown number of RelativeLayouts?

Tags: android

I have an activity that should display X RelativeLayouts, where X is the length of a JSON array. How can I do this?

So far, I have tried this:

```
RelativeLayout[] interestLayouts = new RelativeLayout[jarr.length()];
for (int interest = 0; interest < jarr.length(); interest++) {
    interestLayouts[interest] = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.X); // I don't know how to determine X
}
```

Comment: Show what you have tried

Comment: You could use a `Listview` or `RecyclerView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the Relative Layout dynamically.

```
Linear LAYOUT;  // suppose this is the layout where you want to add relativelayout

for (int i  =0;i < jsonarray.length; i++){
  Relative rLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
  LAYOUT.addView(rLayout);
}
```

something like this

Comment: How would this work if the RelativeLayout is supposed to contain a TextView?